# Обработка исключений с++

Tags: c++, исключения, try-catch

Как обработать исключение, которое возникает при попытке инициализировать значение за  пределами массива, или при чтении из-за его пределов. Пробовал в catch писать "exception e", но оно не ловит.

Comment: Какого массива? Если речь о `std::vector`, то используйте функцию `at()` вместо перегруженных квадратных скобок.

Comment: Если обычный массив - то никак. Доверяет C++ программисту... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

если это встроенный `c++` массив то можно ставить ассерты перед каждым доступом к его элементу -

```
#define array_size 100
int v[array_size];

int i = 100;
assert(i >= 0 && i < array_size); // бросит исключение
v[i] = 123;
```

если у вас `std::vector`

то как уже сказали в комментариях - воспользоваться функцией членом `std::vector::at`
которая гарантированно бросит исключение при выходе за пределы вектора.

```
std::vector<float> v(5);
v.at(5) = 1.0f; // бросит исключение
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле в случае выхода за границу массива происходит исключение уровня операционной системы, после чего программе присылается сигнал об этом, и она падает (в комментариях меня поправят, если это не так, но общий смысл такой).
Корректная реакция на такие сигналы - завершение программы, поскольку они вызываются недопустимыми операциями и после них программа может не находится в консистентном состоянии.

Однако, если очень хочется, то можно такую ошибку отловить и продолжить работу (при этом следует очень хорошо понимать зачем и почему понадобилось так делать, поскольку затея эта целиком и полностью не здоровая).

В основе обработки таких ошибок лежат функции `setjmp` и `longjmp`, позволяющие сохранить состояние программы и вернутся к сохраненному ранее состоянию. Так же нужно отловить сигнал операционной системы, что делается везде по-своему (Для `POSIX`-систем достаточно обычных обработчиков сигналов, для `windows` стоит использовать `Structured Exception Handling` или `Vectored Exception Handling`).

Итак. Регистрируем обработчик (пример для `POSIX`).

```
struct sigaction act;
memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
act.sa_handler = signalHandler;
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0);
```

В обработчике сигнала возвращаемся к сохраненному состоянию и передаем не нулевое значение в качестве возвращаемого для `setjmp`:

```
jmp_buf env;

static void signalHandler(int signum) {
    longjmp(env, 1);
}
```

Перед входом в опасный блок сохраняем состояние программы:

```
try {
    if (setjmp(env))
        throw std::runtime_error("Some shit");

    // Действия, которые могут уронить программу
```

Ловим брошенное исключение:

```
} catch (std::runtime_error & e) {
    // Что-то делаем
}
```

Как оно работает. Функция `setjmp` при сохранении возвращает `0` - исключение не кидается. Если дальше происходит ошибка, то `longjmp` возвращает выполнение к `setjmp`, которое в этот момент вернет `1` - бросится исключение, которое можно обработать.

Данный пример дает лишь общее представление о логике обработки таких ошибок, для использования его на практике, его стоит доработать. Более полное описание чего куда и зачем можно найти тут: [Habrahabr: Обработка многократно возникающих SIGSEGV-подобных ошибок](https://habrahabr.ru/post/332626/)

Comment: Вот явный выход за пределы массива - https://ideone.com/rOJDkC - и ничего, операционная система не шлет никакие сигналы, программа не падает.